Best model for enforcing corporate naming conventions
I'm working on a project (Python) to enforce the company naming convention of products on product lists provided by clients/suppliers. I'm having a list of company names (Standardised names) and those of external. I'm considering typos too - generating this list using GPT.
Here's are the models I'm considering:
Sequence-to-Sequence (Seq2Seq): LTSM over RNN
Transformer-Based Models: BERT on custom data
Additionally, I'm looking up fuzzy string matching.
Could anyone recommend other approaches, or if I'm missing something?
Greatly appreciated :)
Edit:
This a sample of the dataset I'm dealing with. This is the correct names. I'm creating my own dataset with around 20 incorrect names alongside the correct ones. There are about 20k+ unique names.


Could you provide some sample data. This will help others understand your problem well and give relevant answers.

Hi @VidyadharRao, thanks for the suggestion. I've added a snip of the dataset.

"Additionally, I'm looking up fuzzy string matching."
Did you already try fuzzy string matching algorithms instead of some models. I could imagine they suit your needs better.
